# my code compiles, but does not show the expected output

Tags: java

This is my programming homework assignment, it successfully compiles but when I try to run it the output doesn't look like how it is supposed to.  Any suggestions on mistakes that I have made would be much appreciated.  Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/***********************************
 * Class: FRUnit5.java
 * Author: Robert Frankele
 *
 * Description: Ask user to enter the maximum random number of rounds (2-8).
 * Then ask the user how many rounds they would like to execute (1-8).
 * Display the results in formatted columns as follows:
 * (example using 8 as max random number, and 2 and number of rounds)
 *
 * Round    Rand #      Rand^Round      Modulus     Rand/Round
 *     1         7               7            0           7.00
 *     2         4              16            0           2.00
 */
public class FRUnit5
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a Scanner object for user input: 2pts
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Variable to hold user's input for maximum random number: 2pts
        double maxRandNum;
        // Variable to hold the number of rounds the user wishes to execute: 2pts
        double numRound;
        double maxRound;

        // Variable to hold the random number generated from the Math class
        // using the user's maximum random number as an argument: 2pts
        double randNumMath;
        // Ask the user to enter the maximum random number to use (2-8): 2pts
        System.out.print("Enter the maximum random number to use ");
        // Store the number they entered into the variable declared above: 2pts
        maxRandNum = userInput.nextInt();
        // Clear the buffer
        userInput.nextLine();

        // Check to see if the number they entered is greater than 8: 5pts
        // If it is, display an error message and assign 8 as the maximum random number (see project example): 3pts
        // Then, assign 8 to the variable declared above that will hold the maximum random number: 3pts
            if (maxRandNum > 8)
        {
            System.out.println("The maximum random number has to be <= 8");
            maxRandNum = 8;
        }

        // Ask the user to enter the number of rounds they wish to execute.: 2pts
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rounds you wish to execute ");
        // Store the number they entered into the variable declared above: 2pts
        numRound = userInput.nextInt();

        // Print the header of the output, using the printf method: 8pts
        // Round    Rand #      Rand^Round      Modulus     Rand/Round
        System.out.printf("%10s%10s%15s%12s%15s\n", "Round", "Rand #", "Rand^Round", "Modulus", "Rand/Round");

        // Set up a for loop to iterate through the number of rounds: 10pts

        maxRound = 9;
        for (numRound = 0; numRound < maxRound; numRound++)
        {
            // Calculate the random number given the maximum random number, and store in a local variable called randomNum: 5pts
            int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * maxRandNum + 1);


            // Calculate the Rand^Round number, using Math.pow(randomNum, round) as the equation,
            // and store in a local variable called randToRound: 5pts
            double randToRound = (Math.pow(randomNum, numRound));

            // Calculate the modulus: randomNum % round, and store in a variable called modulusOfRand: 3pts
            double modulusOfRand = randomNum % numRound;

            // Calculate randomNum / round and store in a variable called randDivRound: 3pts
            double randDivRound = randomNum / numRound;

            // Using printf, display the results, remembering to only display randDivRound with two places after the decimal point: 10pts
            System.out.printf("%10d%10d%15d%12d%15.2f\n", numRound, randomNum, randToRound, modulusOfRand, randDivRound);

        }

    } // end of main
} // end of class
```

This is what I am seeing:
Enter the maximum random number to use 9
The maximum random number has to be <= 8
Enter the number of rounds you wish to execute 6
     Round    Rand #     Rand^Round     Modulus     Rand/Round
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
        at FRUnit5.main(FRUnit5.java:76)
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Please strongly consider putting more effort into your question and telling us more pertinent and helpful information. For instance -- what output are you expecting? What are you seeing?

Comment: Also, you state that `"it won't run"` -- but then later state that `"...when I try to run it the output doesn't look like how it is supposed to."` -- suggesting that the program **does** in fact run, but just doesn't show you what you expect to see. Again, please clarify.

Comment: The program does run, but does not show the variables in the formatted "printf" that I was expecting. This is what I am seeing:

Comment: Don't put important stuff in comments. Please edit your question, get rid of the "doesn't run" nonsense, because your program in fact **does** run, and please post all the error messages again in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you're getting a `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException`.

make sure you use `%f` instead of `%d` in your `printf()` for variables of type `double` because `%d` goes with a decimal integer in Java.

change this:

```
System.out.printf("%10d%10d%15d%12d%15.2f\n", numRound, randomNum, randToRound, modulusOfRand, randDivRound);
```

to this:

```
System.out.printf("%10f%10d%15f%12f%15.2f\n", numRound, randomNum, randToRound, modulusOfRand, randDivRound);
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right that was the issue.  I appreciate your help!  It's frustrating when you write all that code and then the last line is what has the error.

Comment: glad it helped. don't forget to mark as accepted if the solution has solved your problem ^^.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for failure of the program is the formatting in the System.out.printf() method. You have defined variables randToRound , modulusOfRand as double but you are trying to format them as int by using %10d in the formatter.

Please add System.out.print() to check the values of variables and add appropriate formatting in the System.out.printf(), this should solve your problem.

possible solution:

```
System.out.printf("%10d%10d%15d%12d%15.2f\n", (int)numRound, randomNum, (int)randToRound, (int)modulusOfRand,
                    randDivRound);
```

Also your loop for numRound should start with 1 and loop through numRound current logic will run the loop 9 times which is not what is expeccted in the problem statement.